# Unable to download osm2po from the original site

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting

I've been trying to download the osm2po tool, in order to import the openstreetmap data into postgis database, from the original site and is impossible for me. All links I find in the page are cyclic, return to the main page and I can't find the way to access the tool. Any body can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was able to download osm2po from [this link](http://osm2po.de/download.php?lnk=osm2po-4.7.7.zip), which is found at [osm2po.de](http://osm2po.de/). Is this for what you are looking?

Answer (score 1):

The download from osm2po (as identified by Paul) does work, but it requires javascript to work. It worked with a recent (Firefox) browser, but not with curl or wget for me. Suggest disabling any script blocking extensions you may have before retrying the download.